# Getting Error while creating app identifier in apple developer account(Enterprise account)

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to create app identifier on my enterprise apple developer account with my bundle id. But I am not able to generate app identifier. I am getting following error.

[image]

I don't understand why I am getting this kind of error.

Comment: That bundle ID is already used somewhere. Either in your account or some other account. Even enterprise apps must have a bundle ID that is unique across the App Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bundle ID resource represents the app's unique identifier. Your Bundle ID is **already used** so You have to **use another bundle id**.